# zfs disk drive letter changed. how to reimport by id

Tags: zfs, import

I had a power outage that caused my drives to shuffle their assignment.  `/dev/sdk` is now assigned to a drive in a different pool.  I have been searching around but not found a proper way so far to assign a disk/by-id/ listing to the broken pool as the disk still exists with no errors.

I've tried `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_HGST.... <disk pool>`  but it errors with `pool exists`.
here is a listing of the pool

```
NAME                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
disks                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
 mirror-0                DEGRADED     0     0     0
  6016369452066203690    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sdk1
  sdj                    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

previously I had recorded drives and their sdX mapping

```
scsi-SATA_HGST_HUS726060AL_AR31051EJP72EJ -> ../../sdk
```

which is now

```
scsi-SHGST_HUS726060AL5210_K1GJGWED -> ../../sdk
```

and the former sdk is now [which was part of the disks pool]

```
scsi-SATA_HGST_HUS726060AL_AR31051EJP72EJ -> ../../sdl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: The `import -d` option is not meant to specify the drives, but the directory in which they are exposed:

```
zpool import [-d dir | -c cachefile] [-D]
    Lists pools available to import. If the -d option is not specified, this command searches for devices in "/dev/dsk". The -d option can be specified multiple times, and all directories are searched. 
...
    -d dir 
    Searches for devices or files in dir. The -d option can be specified multiple times. 
...
```

For more information on the usage of `zpool`, have a look into `man zpool`.

About the drive that ended up in a different pool: I cannot imagine how that ended up happening. Try removing it from the different pool with `zfs remove`

The following should import your pool with disk ID:

1. Try `zpool import` without any argument, it should list you the available pools.
2. Import the pool by name with `zpool import <poolname>`
3. check the status with `zpool status` and make sure that there are no errors and wait for any resilvering to be finished before proceeding.
4. export the pool with `zpool export`
5. then reimport with `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ <poolname>`, only specifying the directory, not the drives files itself.
6. If necessary, you can specify a new pool name with `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ <poolname> <newpoolname>`

Comment: originally when the mirror was created it was sdj and sdk that were assigned to it.  I cant remember if it was before I had read about the issues with by sdX or i was testing somethng and forgot to remake it with disk/by-id/xxxx.   after the power outage the sdX assignments got shuffled. I think i had hot added one of the new drives recently and this was the first reboot since then so the pool got confused.

Comment: so would the suggestion be to export the pool and then re import it so it can find the new sdX pair?

Comment: @Kendrick Yes, that is exactly what I was suggesting. ZFS should be capable of finding the drives by itself, as long as you invoke a manual export and import.

Comment: just import and export worked.  it wouldn't take by id for some reason

Comment: @Kendrick you better find a way to reimport it by ID before the next outage happens.

Comment: yup im in the process of backing up all my data so that i can destroy all pools and then recreate them in a better manner now that i have enough disks to do different pool types. murphy's law kicked in...